# definition of dec norm

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

The dec norm is defined as in the sceenshot. I met with some troubles when I check it is indeed a norm.

It is obvious that$\|u\|_{dec}\geq 0$, but how to check it satifies the triangle inequality and $\|u\|_{dec}=0\Rightarrow u=0$.

Comment: What is $\|\cdot\|_{dec}$ supposed to be a norm on? Rather than post a screen shot, could you type up this info, and add a link to the relevant pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\|u\|_{dec}=0$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$; then there exist $S_1,S_2$ with $\|S_1\|\leq\varepsilon$, $\|S_2\|\leq\varepsilon$ and 
$$
Vx=\begin{bmatrix} S_1(x) & u(x)\\ u(x^*)^*& S_2(x)\end{bmatrix} 
$$
completely positive. Taking $x\geq0$, we get 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} S_1(x) & u(x)\\ u(x^*)^*& S_2(x)\end{bmatrix} \geq0 
$$
in $M_2(B)$. It is well-known that such a $2\times 2$ block matrix being positive implies that there exists a contraction $y(x)$ with 
$$
u(x)=(S_1(x)+\varepsilon I)^{1/2}y(x)(S_2(x)+\varepsilon I)^{1/2}.
$$
Then 
$$
\|u(x)\|\leq\|(S_1(x)+\varepsilon I)^{1/2}\|\,\|(S_2(x)+\varepsilon I)^{1/2}\|
\leq2\varepsilon. 
$$
As this can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$, we obtain that $u(x)=0$.

For the triangle inequality, if 
$$
Vx=\begin{bmatrix} S_1(x) & u(x)\\ u(x^*)^*& S_2(x)\end{bmatrix} 
,\ \ \ \ 
Wx=\begin{bmatrix} T_1(x) & v(x)\\ v(x^*)^*& T_2(x)\end{bmatrix} 
$$
are completely positive, so is 
$$
(V+W)x=\begin{bmatrix} S_1(x)+T_1(x) & u(x)+v(x) \\ u(x^*)^*+v(x^*)^*& S_2(x)+T_2(x)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus 
\begin{align}
\|u+v\|_{dec}&\leq \max\{\|S_1+T_1\|,\|S_2+T_2\|\}
\leq\max\{\|S_1\|+\|T_1\|,\|S_2\|+\|T_2\|\}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\max\{\|S_1\|,\|S_2\|\}+\max\{\|T_1\|,\|T_2\|\}.
\end{align}
Then
$$
\|u+v\|_{dec}-\max\{\|S_1\|,\|S_2\|\}\leq\max\{\|T_1\|,\|T_2\|\}
$$
for any choice of $S_1,S_2$ and $T_1,T_2$ that appear in the decompositions of $u$ and $v$ respectively. So the left hand side is a lower bound for the right-hand-side, and we get
$$
\|u+v\|_{dec}-\max\{\|S_1\|,\|S_2\|\}\leq\|v\|_{dec}.
$$
Now rewrite this as 
$$
\|u+v\|_{dec}-\|v\|_{dec}\leq\max\{\|S_1\|,\|S_2\|\},
$$
to get $\|u+v\|_{dec}-\|v\|_{dec}\leq\|u\|_{dec}$.

---

**Edit: Existence of the contraction.**

If $$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\ B^*& C\end{bmatrix}\geq0,$$ then$$\begin{bmatrix}A+\varepsilon I&B\\ B^*& C+\varepsilon I\end{bmatrix}\geq0,$$so multiplying left and right with $\begin{bmatrix}(A+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}&0\\0&(C+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}\end{bmatrix}$ we have $$\begin{bmatrix}I&(A+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}B(C+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}\\(C+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}B^*(A+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2} & I\end{bmatrix}\geq0,$$
which is equivalent to $\|Y\|\leq1$, where $Y=(A+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}B(C+\varepsilon I)^{-1/2}$. So
$$
B=(A+\varepsilon I)^{1/2}Y(C+\varepsilon I)^{1/2},
$$
with $\|Y\|\leq1$.

Comment: I don't undersatnd why there exist a contraction $y(x)$ with $\cdots$

Comment: It's a basic manipulation with block matrices. I have edited a bit in.

Comment: I have another question: How to conclude that $\|Y\|\leq 1$? If the matrix the a real matrix, the determinant of a positive definitive matrix is positive.

Comment: These are block matrices, so dealing with determinants makes little sense here. You are reading theorems about block matrices, it is an easy exercise to determine when a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} I& R\\ R^*& I\end{bmatrix} $i is positive.

Comment: ， would you mind recommending some reference books about block matrices involving operators? Thanks

Comment: Your last question is Lemma 3.1 in Paulsen's book. You should take a look at the relevant parts in chapters 1-3. I don't know another reference of the top of my head (there are probably several).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just saw the proof of lemma. The author set $A=\pi(a)$ and prove \begin{bmatrix} I& A\\ A^*& I\end{bmatrix} is positive. Pro Martin, how to conclude that
\begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ a^*& 1\end{bmatrix} is positive via the positivity of  \begin{bmatrix} I& A\\ A^*& I\end{bmatrix}

Comment: It looks like you only read the first sentence of the proof, which is the one that is completely irrelevant to your question! There's no $\pi$ for you, you need to understand how to characterize when such matrix is positive.

Comment: Pro Martin, I found a problem. In the above you proved the existence of contraction. But we cannoy view $u(x)$ as $B$, since $u(x^*)^*\neq u(x)^*$.

Comment: The argument starts with taking $x\geq0$, so $x^*=x$.